# Second order homogeneous ode with non constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find two linear independent solutions in the form $t^b$ for the ode:

$$y''+\frac{1-a^2}{4t^2}y=0$$

How do I do this? Should I try the power series method?

I think I have to find one solution for $a=1$ and one for $a\neq0$?

Comment: Solutions of this ODE are *not* of the form $t^b$. Perhaps you wanted a $t^2$ in the denominator in front of $y$? Then it's a Cauchy-Euler equation.

Comment: You are right I didn't copy it right, it's indeed $t^2$ (I edited it). Any ideas how I should go on with this problem?

Comment: Now you can simply use the ansatz $y(t) = t^b$ in the ODE and find values of $b$ such that it is satisfied.

Comment: You don't seem to have tried a lot.

Comment: @SlimJim I would recommend you _try_ to solve it, then if you are stuck you can come back to ask for help. Since you said "should I try the power series method", it is clear that you have an idea, so why not play with it and see if you are correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$b(b-1)t^{b-2}+\frac{1-a^2}4t^{b-2}=0$$ is an identity when

$$b(b-1)+\frac{1-a^2}4=\left(b-\frac12\right)^2-\frac{a^2}4=0.$$

Comment: Your hint was very useful. I used it and I found $b=\frac{a+1}{2}$ and the first solution $y_1=t^{\frac{a+1}{2}}=\sqrt{t^{a+1}}$. Now for the second solution to be independent it must be $y_2=t^blnt$ right?

Comment: @SlimJim: The second solution is in front of your eyes, but $a=0$ remains a special case.

Answer (score 1):

$$t^2y''+\frac{1-a^2}{4}y=0$$
By inspection you should recognize an Euler's homogeneous differential equation. This is one of the simplest to solve and one of the first taught.

For particular solutions on the form $t^r$ the characteristic equation is :
$$r(r-1)+\frac{1-a^2}{4}=0$$
The solutions of this quadratic equation are :
$$r=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4\frac{1-a^2}{4}}}{2}=\frac{1\pm a}{2}$$
The general solution is :
$$y(t)=c_1 t^{(1+a)/2}+c_2 t^{(1-a)/2}$$

NOTE :

You get the characteristic equation in putting into the ODE $y=t^r\quad;\quad y'=rt^{r-1}\quad;\quad y''=r(r-1)t^{r-2}$.